# How can I count the digits of a number with leading zeroes in python

Tags: python, digits

In a number without leading zeroes I would do this

```
import math
num = 1001
digits = int(math.log10(num))+1
print (digits)

>>> 4
```

but if use a number with leading zeroes like "0001" I get

`SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`

I would like to be able to count the digits including the leading zeroes. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: How is `1` meaningfully different from `01`, `001`, etc?

Comment: I'm feading it into a software called Nuke that reads image sequences and it expects a format like "imageseg.%04d.jpg" so if the images are numbered 0001 - 0234 I get an error.

Comment: Show us some actual code with an actual error.  Otherwise we are just guessing at your real problem.

Comment: Thanks John. I was trying to simplify a lot of code but I guess I was over thinking it. Looking at the answer from ti7 I could just use `len(num)`. I'm going to go think about how dumb I am now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reasonably have a number with leading digits unless it's a string!

Therefore, if you're accepting a string, just remove them and check the difference in length

```py
>>> value         = input("enter a number: ")
enter a number: 0001
>>> value_clean   = value.lstrip("0")
>>> leading_zeros = len(value) - len(value_clean)
>>> print("leading zeros: {}".format(leading_zeros))
leading zeros: 3
```

If you only wanted the number from a bad input, `int()` can directly convert it for you instead

```py
>>> int("0001")
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb. The answer was simple. All I needed was:

```
num = 0001
num_string = str(num) 
print (len(num_string))
```

result:

```
>>> 4
```

Comment: this doesn't work and results in a `SyntaxError`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).